# Getting list of items from firebase swift

Tags: swift, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im have a database like this:

[image: Database]

The user will be able to favorite the places. I save the favorited places by saving the ids. I want to only get the favorited places from the database by using the IDs. I can´t figure out how to do this. Please help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase Swift 3 get list of child in a array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40117849/firebase-swift-3-get-list-of-child-in-a-array)

Comment: @MacLean Two things; the answer in the linked question was a fix for a typo (FDatabase vs FIRDatabase) and more importantly, the structure of Firebase in this question is not an array, Firebase Arrays are sequential and numerical (keys of 0, 1, 2, 3 etc)

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are asking how to get a place by it's ID

(Swift 4, Firebase 4)

> get the favorited places from the database by using the IDs

This will read a single place, placeId1

```
let placeRef = self.ref.child("places").child("placeId1")

placeRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    let placeDict = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]
    let info = placeDict["info"] as! String
    let moreInfo = placeDict["moreinfo"] as! String
    print(info, moreinfo)
})
```

this will read all the places (at once) and iterate over them

```
    let allPlaces = self.ref.child("places")

    allPlaces.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        for child in snapshot.children {
            let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
            let placeDict = snap.value as! [String: Any]
            let info = placeDict["info"] as! String
            let moreInfo = placeDict["moreinfo"] as! String
            print(info, moreInfo)
        }
    })
```

note: self.ref = Database.database().reference()

Comment: what if I have a list as an attribute next to info and moreinfo, how can I read that?

Comment: @Edu Are you asking; 'what if the key of *info* has a value that's a list of child nodes'? i.e. places/placeId1/info/child_0: value_0 and places/placeId1/info/child_1: value_0 etc. If so, info can be treated as a snapshot, e.g. let infoSnap = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "info"). Then the value of infoSnap can be iterated over or read the child nodes as a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to check each place id with your stored favorite place ids.

```
ref.child("places").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

    var newItems = [FIRDataSnapshot]() 

    for item in snapshot.children {

        if let value = (item as! FIRDataSnapshot).value as? String {
             // might want to do another loop if you have an array of places to check

           if snapshot.value as? String == "favorite_place_id" {
             // this is what you want
           }

        }

    }
})
```

Comment: You may want to double check the code on this answer as reading by .childAdded will return each node separately and the children will be info, moreinfo etc. and the values will be Infotext, Infotexts, none of which will be the place id (the key, which is what the OP wanted)

Comment: i think this is what i want! But i can´t figure out where to put the loop and how to write it..

Comment: @user1953498 This code isn't an answer to your question (unless I misunderstood the question/unclear). In general looping over nodes is a pretty inefficient way to locate data you are looking for.

Comment: oh, okay. hmm, i am trying to just download the date with the right ids, not the whole database then filter out the right ids..

Answer (score 0):

```
self.ref.child("places").observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
            for child in snapshot.children {
                let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
            let placeDict = snap.value as! [String: Any]
            let info = placeDict["info"] as! String
            let moreInfo = placeDict["moreinfo"] as! String
            print(info, moreInfo)
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.